# を and と used with 考える

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, particle-と, particle-を

I thought that 考える was used like 思う in that particle と always preceded it. However I found the following sentence from a reading task for class:

> まるで**英語を公用語と考えている**かのように、英語の言葉を多く使う。

What does it mean and what roles do を and と play in relation to the verb 考える?

Answer (score 4):

英語**を**公用語**と**考える means "to think of 英語 as 公用語".